# Terminal gets closed as soon as I start it

Tags: bash, terminal, ubuntu-16.04, profile

I have newly given ubuntu 16.04.
I wanted my terminal to execute command during start up so I go to:

```
Edit -> profile preferences -> run a custom command instead of my shell
```

There I wrote the command:

```
zsh && cal (maybe a semi-colon in the end also)
```

But now when I am opening terminal using CTRL+ALT+T or opening terminal using GUI it is getting closed. So I cannot change terminal setting also.

How can I reverse this or atleast change that setting so atleast I can open the terminal.

Comment: (1) Do you know for sure that your system *has* `zsh`?  (2) More to the point: can you rename your ``.bashrc`` to something (e.g., ``.bashrc.hold``) from the GUI?

Comment: (1) yes I just install it and before writing zsh && cal I wrote the command zsh and it was working fine.   (2) yes I can rename

Comment: If the `.bashrc` is causing your problem (as seems likely, although I don’t see exactly how or why), then renaming it should make the problem go away.

Comment: But I have renamed it and still the problem remains and also tried deleting .bashrc

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say everything that you have tried and what resulted.

Comment: Thank you very much and the problem is solved. I actually  made another file and opened it using vim. And strangely the setting of vim is same as terminal so the go to the Edit -> Profile preferences -> run a custom command instead of my shell and cleared the command and the problem it solved. Still I have no idea what was causing the problem as when I run the command on bash terminal zsh && cal it works fine. But still thank you @Scott for giving your time.